# Not able to show custom query products in carousal in wordpress woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins, shortcode

I'm using this custom shortcode to query the products `[products columns="5" limit="10" attribute="pa_color" terms="red" terms_operator="AND" best_selling="true"]` .I have tried a number of plugins to display the products in carousal mode but none of them worked.
Plugins tried:
 1) *Woo products slider pro*
 2) *Product slider and carousel with category for woocommerce* 
Can anyone suggest any alternate plugin or a workaround for this?
PS: The shortcode mentioned is just for reference I have adapted the shortcode for different plugins.

Comment: Give us a code that you have tried. Describe which carousel library you want to use.

Comment: @MartinMirchev The reference shortcode is mentioned in the description. I have used the `do_shortcode()` method in PHP to display the products. Suggest me any plugin or library to display the products in carousel mode.

Comment: _"Suggest me any plugin or library"_. Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. -> [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) <-

Answer (score 1):

The following example is using slick carousel. Please read theyr documentation to abjust to your needs. https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ .

**PHP part** Place the code in your functions.php file

```
function carousel_required_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style('slick-styles','//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css');
    wp_enqueue_script('slick','//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js',array('jquery'));
    // Create js file in your theme and use it to customize your carousel
    wp_enqueue_script('slick-settings', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/assets/js/slick-settings.js',array('slick'));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','carousel_required_scripts');


//Shortcode output
function my_product_shortcode( $atts, $content) {

    $output[] = carousel_get_products( $atts );

    return sprintf(
        '<div class="slick-carousel-wrap woocommerce">%s</div>',
        implode( '', $output )
    );
}

// Custom query where we can use custom attributes from our shortcode
function carousel_get_products($atts) {
    global $woocommerce_loop;

    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'total-items' => '5', // Default value if we dont set
        ), $atts
    );

    $args = array(
        'post_type'           => 'product',
        'post_status'         => 'publish',
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
        'posts_per_page'      => $atts['total-items'],
    );

    $output     = '';
    ob_start();
    $products = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $products->have_posts() ) :

        while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post();
            wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
        endwhile;

    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    $output = ob_get_clean();
    return $output;
}

// Register our shortcode. Usage example: [mycarousel total-items="10"]
function mycarousel_shortcodes_init() {
    add_shortcode( 'mycarousel', 'my_product_shortcode' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'mycarousel_shortcodes_init' );
```

**jQuery part**

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.slick-carousel-wrap').slick({
        dots: true, // default settings if responsive not set
        infinite: false, // default settings if responsive not set
        speed: 300, // default settings if responsive not set
        slidesToShow: 3, // default settings if responsive not set
        slidesToScroll: 1,// default settings if responsive not set
        responsive: [
          {
            breakpoint: 1024,
            settings: {
              slidesToShow: 3,
              slidesToScroll: 3,
              infinite: true,
              dots: true
            }
          },
          {
            breakpoint: 600,
            settings: {
              slidesToShow: 2,
              slidesToScroll: 2
            }
          },
          {
            breakpoint: 480,
            settings: {
              slidesToShow: 1,
              slidesToScroll: 1
            }
          }
          // You can unslick at a given breakpoint now by adding:
          // settings: "unslick"
          // instead of a settings object
        ]
    });
 });
```